# mariaDB 10.5.8 very slow stored view after moving to newer version

Tags: mysql, performance, view, mariadb

I would like to ask for help as I'm struggling to understand this issue.

I have two databases main and backup. Both have same data and views. Main is inside VM on QNAP NAS (v10.5.5) and backup is on same NAS but installed natively (v10.5.8). I know this is bad idea but this is only a test setup I'm working on.

Issue I have is with stored views. On the VM they would return result in less then 1s, but directly on NAS it takes up to 70s for exactly the same data set and view. It doesn't matter what view I use they are all slow on the backup DB. I tried to adjust settings in the mariadb.conf on NAS to increase buffers but no change made any difference at all. Only one function reduced the wait by 10s, skip-name-resolve. I have tried to run it via phpMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench and terminal directly on the NAS, result is always the same ~70s or sometimes even slower. Again on main DB inside VM they take less than 1s. That fact makes me think this is a config issue more than views themself.

Here is my config file for mariaDB:

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir = /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.mariadb10/tmp
#skip-networking
user=admin
skip-external-locking
socket = /var/run/mariadb10.sock
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 2M
net_buffer_length = 16K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
#default-storage-engine = MyISAM
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
pid-file = /var/lock/mariadb10.pid
log-error = /var/log/mariadb10/mariadb.err
skip-name-resolve
```

I have compared output of SHOW VARIABLES; on both and the only big difference is that main DB uses rocksdb where backup is not.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong or what I'm missing? Please let me know if you need any extra information.

Kind Regards

UPDATE:

Main explain output:
[image]
[image]

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | r_rows | filtered | r_filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '1' | 'PRIMARY' | '' | 'ALL' | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | '44803765561' | '0.00' | '100.00' | '100.00' | 'Using where' |
| '2' | 'DERIVED' | 'q1' | 'ALL' | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | '211669' | '227012.00' | '100.00' | '0.00' | 'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort' |
| '2' | 'DERIVED' | '' | 'ALL' | 'distinct_key' | NULL | NULL | NULL | '211669' | NULL | '100.00' | NULL | 'Using join buffer (flat |
| '2' | 'DERIVED' | 'sic_report' | 'eq_ref' | 'PRIMARY' | 'PRIMARY' | '4' | '.max(`SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`id`)' | '1' | NULL | '100.00' | NULL | 'Using where' |
| '4' | 'MATERIALIZED' | 'sic_report' | 'ALL' | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | '211669' | NULL | '100.00' | NULL | 'Using temporary' |

Backup explain output:
[image]
[image]

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | r_rows | filtered | r_filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '1' | 'PRIMARY' | '' | 'ALL' | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | '230068224' | '1.00' | '100.00' | '100.00' | 'Using where' |
| '2' | 'DERIVED' | 'q1' | 'ALL' | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | '15168' | '15586.00' | '100.00' | '100.00' | 'Using temporary; Using filesort' |
| '2' | 'DERIVED' | 'sic_report' | 'ALL' | 'PRIMARY' | NULL | NULL | NULL | '15168' | '15586.00' | '100.00' | '0.19' | 'Using where; Using join buffer (flat |
| '2' | 'DERIVED' | '' | 'eq_ref' | 'distinct_key' | 'distinct_key' | '4' | 'SOME_DB.sic_report.id' | '1' | '0.03' | '100.00' | '100.00' | '' |
| '4' | 'MATERIALIZED' | 'sic_report' | 'ALL' | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | '15168' | '15586.00' | '100.00' | '100.00' | 'Using temporary' |

Example view:

```
CREATE 
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `v_sic_stats` AS
SELECT 
    `q1`.`date_time` AS `date_time`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`lines_`, 0) AS `lines_`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`stations`, 0) AS `stations_avg`,
    IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(NULLIF(`q1`.`spol`, 0)), 1), 0) AS `spol_avg`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`actual_pick`, 0) AS `actual_pick`,
    IFNULL(ROUND(NULLIF(`q2`.`lines_`, 0) / NULLIF(`q2`.`stations`, 0),
                    0),
            0) AS `delivery_rate`,
    IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(NULLIF(`q1`.`src_order_pool`, 0)), 0),
            0) AS `src_pool`,
    IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(NULLIF(`q1`.`wms_order_pool`, 0)), 0),
            0) AS `wms_pool`,
    IFNULL(ROUND(`q2`.`avg_pick_time` / `q2`.`lines_`, 1),
            0) AS `avg_pick_time`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`sort_ff_c`, 0) AS `sort_ff_c`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`sort_ff_dt`, '00:00:00') AS `sort_ff_dt`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`sort_gf_c`, 0) AS `sort_gf_c`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`sort_gf_dt`, '00:00:00') AS `sort_gf_dt`,
    IFNULL(MAX(CAST(`q1`.`sort_check_gf` AS DECIMAL (10 , 0 ))),
            0) AS `sort_check_gf`,
    IFNULL(MAX(CAST(`q1`.`sort_check_ff` AS DECIMAL (10 , 0 ))),
            0) AS `sort_check_ff`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk01_sort_occupation`, 0) AS `tk01_sort_occupation`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk02_sort_occupation`, 0) AS `tk02_sort_occupation`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk01_sort_reloops`, 0) AS `tk01_sort_reloops`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk02_sort_reloops`, 0) AS `tk02_sort_reloops`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk01_emp_occ`, 0) AS `tk01_emp_occ`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk01_emp_relop`, 0) AS `tk01_emp_relop`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk02_emp_occ`, 0) AS `tk02_emp_occ`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk02_emp_relop`, 0) AS `tk02_emp_relop`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`pick_order_lead_time`, 0) AS `pick_order_lead_time`,
    IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(`q1`.`pick_order_postp_count`), 0),
            0) AS `pick_order_postp_count`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk01_err_occ`, 0) AS `tk01_err_occ`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk01_err_relop`, 0) AS `tk01_err_relop`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk02_err_occ`, 0) AS `tk02_err_occ`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk02_err_relop`, 0) AS `tk02_err_relop`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`stations_tk01`, 0) AS `stations_tk01`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`stations_tk02`, 0) AS `stations_tk02`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk01_sf_sorter`, 0) AS `tk01_sf_sorter`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk01_sf_prezone`, 0) AS `tk01_sf_prezone`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk02_sf_sorter`, 0) AS `tk02_sf_sorter`,
    IFNULL(`q2`.`tk02_sf_prezone`, 0) AS `tk02_sf_prezone`
FROM
    (`SOME_DB`.`sic_report` `q1`
    JOIN (SELECT 
        `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`id` AS `id`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`date_time` AS `date_time`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`lines_` AS `lines_`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`stations` AS `stations`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`spol` AS `spol`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`actual_pick` AS `actual_pick`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`created_at` AS `created_at`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`delivery_rate` AS `delivery_rate`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`src_order_pool` AS `src_order_pool`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`src_order_pool_qty` AS `src_order_pool_qty`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`wms_order_pool` AS `wms_order_pool`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`wms_order_pool_qty` AS `wms_order_pool_qty`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`avg_pick_time` AS `avg_pick_time`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`sort_ff_c` AS `sort_ff_c`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`sort_ff_dt` AS `sort_ff_dt`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`sort_gf_c` AS `sort_gf_c`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`sort_gf_dt` AS `sort_gf_dt`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`sort_check_gf` AS `sort_check_gf`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`sort_check_ff` AS `sort_check_ff`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk01_sort_occupation` AS `tk01_sort_occupation`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk02_sort_occupation` AS `tk02_sort_occupation`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk01_sort_reloops` AS `tk01_sort_reloops`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk02_sort_reloops` AS `tk02_sort_reloops`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk01_emp_occ` AS `tk01_emp_occ`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk01_emp_relop` AS `tk01_emp_relop`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk02_emp_occ` AS `tk02_emp_occ`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk02_emp_relop` AS `tk02_emp_relop`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`pick_order_lead_time` AS `pick_order_lead_time`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`pick_order_postp_count` AS `pick_order_postp_count`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk01_err_occ` AS `tk01_err_occ`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk01_err_relop` AS `tk01_err_relop`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk02_err_occ` AS `tk02_err_occ`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk02_err_relop` AS `tk02_err_relop`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`stations_tk01` AS `stations_tk01`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`stations_tk02` AS `stations_tk02`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk01_sf_sorter` AS `tk01_sf_sorter`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk01_sf_prezone` AS `tk01_sf_prezone`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk02_sf_sorter` AS `tk02_sf_sorter`,
            `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`tk02_sf_prezone` AS `tk02_sf_prezone`
    FROM
        `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`
    WHERE
        `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`id` IN (SELECT 
                MAX(`SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`id`)
            FROM
                `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`
            GROUP BY `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`.`date_time`)) `q2` ON (`q1`.`date_time` = `q2`.`date_time`))
WHERE
    `q1`.`date_time` > SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
GROUP BY `q1`.`date_time`
```

UPDATE2:

Main innodb_buffer:

| 'innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size' | '134217728' |
| --- | --- |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown' | 'ON' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now' | 'OFF' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct' | '25' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_filename' | 'ib_buffer_pool' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_instances' | '1' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort' | 'OFF' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup' | 'ON' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_load_now' | 'OFF' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_populate' | 'OFF' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' | '805306368' |

Backup innodb_buffer:

| 'innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size' | '134217728' |
| --- | --- |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown' | 'ON' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now' | 'OFF' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct' | '25' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_filename' | 'ib_buffer_pool' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_instances' | '1' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort' | 'OFF' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup' | 'ON' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_load_now' | 'OFF' |
| 'innodb_buffer_pool_size' | '1073741824' |

Create Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `sic_report` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
`lines_` text DEFAULT NULL,
`stations` text DEFAULT NULL,
`spol` text DEFAULT NULL,
`actual_pick` text DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
`delivery_rate` text DEFAULT NULL,
`src_order_pool` text DEFAULT NULL,
`src_order_pool_qty` text DEFAULT NULL,
`wms_order_pool` text DEFAULT NULL,
`wms_order_pool_qty` text DEFAULT NULL,
`avg_pick_time` text DEFAULT NULL,
`sort_ff_c` text DEFAULT NULL,
`sort_ff_dt` text DEFAULT NULL,
`sort_gf_c` text DEFAULT NULL,
`sort_gf_dt` text DEFAULT NULL,
`sort_check_gf` text DEFAULT NULL,
`sort_check_ff` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk01_sort_occupation` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk02_sort_occupation` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk01_sort_reloops` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk02_sort_reloops` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk01_emp_occ` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk01_emp_relop` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk02_emp_occ` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk02_emp_relop` text DEFAULT NULL,
`pick_order_lead_time` text DEFAULT NULL,
`pick_order_postp_count` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk01_err_occ` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk01_err_relop` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk02_err_occ` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk02_err_relop` text DEFAULT NULL,
`stations_tk01` text DEFAULT NULL,
`stations_tk02` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk01_sf_sorter` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk01_sf_prezone` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk02_sf_sorter` text DEFAULT NULL,
`tk02_sf_prezone` text DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=329266 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Main DB:

| TABLE_NAME | ENGINE | TABLE_ROWS | AVG_ROW_LENGTH | DATA_LENGTH | INDEX_LENGTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'sic_report' | 'InnoDB' | '15644' | '235' | '3686400' | '0' |

Backup DB :

| TABLE_NAME | ENGINE | TABLE_ROWS | AVG_ROW_LENGTH | DATA_LENGTH | INDEX_LENGTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'sic_report' | 'InnoDB' | '16266' | '226' | '3686400' | '0' |

Comment: Check the EXPLAIN output for the query on the two instances to make sure they are the same. It may highlight the issue.

Comment: What is your `innodb_log_file_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`? What RAM is available in VM compared to native? Can you try [analyze tables](https://mariadb.org/mariadb-30x-faster/)? Like what @nnichols said, EXPLAIN or [ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON query](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-format-json/)  could highlight some differences.

Comment: @danblack main => innodb_log_file_size = 50331648 | innodb_buffer_pool_size = 134217728 ; 
backup =>  innodb_log_file_size = 100663296 | innodb_buffer_pool_size = 134217728

Comment: @nnichols I have done the explain, and there is a difference, but I don't know how to interpreter it, I will update main post with the results.

Comment: Please include the EXPLAIN output as markdown tables, not images. https://tableconvert.com/ is a great help for converting tables.

Comment: The actual query would be useful too. Allocating a bigger innodb buffer pool would be good. As much as you can spare.

Comment: Table structures as `show create table xxx` too.

Comment: I have added the extra informaion

Comment: QNAP has 16GB of ram where 4GB is assigned to VM and rest for the NAS to use

Comment: @danblack I have changed the innodb buffer pool to 1024MB and read and write buffers to 256MB

Comment: What MySQL/MariaDB versions in both cases?

Comment: There seem to be more EXPLAINs that cases??

Comment: Why don't the Explains mention `q2`?

Comment: @RickJames versions are right at the top of the post. I don't know why q2 is not mentioned, as I said before I have no experience with use of the explain

Comment: @nnichols I have added the details you have requested. Not sure what you mean by data and index, do you want me to extract it? Row count is 16264. The default storage on main is InnoDB and on backup is InnoDB. But the main table has settings for the RocksDB where backup doesn't. I have added the config extract from main db for the rocksDB setup.

Comment: @nnichols it looks like the backup DB doesn't even have RocksDB installed as a plugin (I believe it is a plugin?), so I can't even turn it on if I wonted to. Plus not sure how I would go about installing plugins for mariaDB on qnap system in the first place. Oh and I know storing everything as text is a not ideal thing to do, but like I said this is just my test setup.

Comment: @nnichols it returns InnoDB on both, I have removed the RocksDB info.

Comment: @nnichols added the output of the query.

Comment: Not really, both finish within 0.1 to 0.2s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249656/discussion-between-nnichols-and-blackegg13).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your table statistics are wildly different so the index choices are different. You can update the stats for these tables with -

```
ANALYZE TABLE table_name_1, table_name_2;
```

Read more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html)

You may also want to look at the underlying query in more detail as it will almost certainly benefit from additional indexing.

**UPDATE** after adding CREATE TABLE statement

There are no indices other than the primary key. Given that you are grouping by and joining on `date_time` there should be an index -

```
ALTER TABLE `SOME_DB`.`sic_report`
    ADD INDEX `idx_date_time` (`date_time`);
```

Comment: I have run that and got status OK on all of them, no change in performance tho.

Answer (score 0):

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 134217728
```

is terrible, especially for such large table like you have.  Set that to about 70% of available RAM -- 12G for the 16GB machine but only 1200M for the smaller one.  These should provide much better performance on both, but the smaller one is likely to be I/O-bound.

Also, avoid the construct `IN ( SELECT ... )`.  Usually that can be changed to a `JOIN`.

How many rows in each table?

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table; there may be some missing `INDEXes`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but, on exactly same innodb_buffer_pool_size the main DB is taking below 1s to process the request so it can't be that value. I have added the create table query to main post. I can try to change the query to use joins, but that doesn't really answer the question why there is such a drastic difference in performance between the two almost same version DB's

Comment: BTW after danblack suggestion I have increased the buffer to 1GB but it made zero difference. The view is as slow as it was to the second.

Comment: @Blackegg13 - Would it work to push `WHERE
    `q1`.`date_time` > SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY` into some (or all) of the subqueries?